# Replace/Append Content Of first <p> tag in string using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to append some string to "Initial Message" using Jquery. I tried finding the

tag and appending to the content but it did not work. How can i do this using Jquery?

```
var stringHtml = '<p>Initial Message</p>'+'<p align="center" style="margin-top: 30px;">'+'<input type="button" id="okPopupButton" name="ok" value="ok"/>';

    I am trying this

    var con = $(stringHtml);
    con.find('<p>').append('<p>Test</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but I believe what you want is the :first selector. Something like that:

```
var stringHtml = '<p>Initial Message</p>'+'<p  align="center" style="margin-top:30px;">'+'<input type="button" id="okPopupButton" name="ok" value="ok"></p>';
var con = $('<div/>').html(stringHtml);

con.find('p:first').append('Test');
```